# New MBPs run out of RAM while older MBPs don't

Tags: hardware, memory

I'm running application tests, spread by ssh across five machines, each running several iPhone simulators.

On the three mid-2015 Sierra machines, I can run seven or so Simulators quite happily.

On the two 2016 touchbar machines, I can only run two or three: even four raise the 'Your system has run out of application memory' dialogue and halts the simulators (not something I've seen on the other macs, where the memory pressure is level at around 33%). I also notice that there's about 1G more 'memory used' on the newer machines, and 1G to 3G more in compressed.

There's only about 10G of swap in use - at least, at the point where Activity Monitor itself is paused(!) - which is about 6G short of where I'd expect problems to start.

I've tried switching the new machines into server mode with `nvram boot-args="serverperfmode=1"` but there's no difference.

The version of XCode and Sierra is the same for both, and both have maxproc increased to 2500 to accommodate the extra simulators, but I don't believe I've tweaked the old machines in any other way, so I'm at a bit of a loss to understand where the difference is aside from hardware.

I can't imagine the touchbar takes up much; is the screen going to eat into application memory? The fingerprint driver?